# yii2 ActiveForm field add html code

Tags: php, field, yii2

I have this code in Yii2:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username',$opzioni)->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Username'));  ?>
```

generate this:

```
<div class="input-icon field-loginform-username required">
    <label class="control-label" for="loginform-username">Username</label>
    <input id="loginform-username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="LoginForm[username]">
    <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

and i want to do this

```
<div class="input-icon field-loginform-username required">
    <label class="control-label" for="loginform-username">Username</label>
    **<i class="fa fa-user"></i>**
    <input id="loginform-username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="LoginForm[username]">
    <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

It's possible with the original source?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the users' answer if it is correct. This site runs on goodwill and reputation :)

Answer (score 41):

refering to http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$template-detail

```
template = "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
```

your code should be like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username', [
  'template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-user'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
])->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Username'));  ?>
```

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'username', ['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-user'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Username'));  ?>

thank you very much!